# JS Adding Row to Table With Link Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, html-table

**EDIT: I got it working! It turned out that I had written innerHtml instead of innerHTML. I This topic can be closed.**

I am trying to use JS to put the link most recently clicked by a userinto a table row where a row is created each time a link is clicked. The list of links shown is also generated using JS.

The problem I am having is that when I click a link, the table is created with an empty row.

Here is the JS.

```
function processLinks()
{
    var linksList = document.links; // get the document's links
    var contents = "";

    for ( var i = 0; i < linksList.length; ++i )
    {
        var currentLink = linksList[ i ];
        contents += "<p style =\"background-color:red\"><a href='" + currentLink.href +  "'    
        target='_blank' id='link" + i + "'>" + 
        currentLink.innerHTML + "</a></p>";
    }

    // if user click link var currentLink = linksList[ index of link user clicked ];
    //create table
    //document.getElementById("link + index to specify element 0,1,2,3, etc for   
    //id").onclick

    document.getElementById( "links" ).innerHTML = contents;

} // end function processLinks

function insertLink(e)
{
    var linksList = document.links; // get the document's links
    var contents = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < linksList.length; ++i)
    {
        if(document.getElementById("link" + i) )
        {
            var currentLink = linksList[i];

            contents += "<p><a href='" + currentLink.href +  "' target='_blank'    
            id='link" + i + "'>" + 
                currentLink.innerHTML + "</a></p>";

            tbody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            var cell = document.createElement("td");

            cell.innerHtml = contents;

            row.appendChild(cell);
            tbody.appendChild(row);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("tableBody").onclick = function(){insertLink()};
}

document.addEventListener("click", insertLink, false);
window.addEventListener( "load", processLinks, false );
```

Comment: Please define "empty row". Is that `<tr />`? `<tr><td><p><a href=""></a><p></td></td><p><a href=""></a></p></td></tr>`?

Comment: create a jsFidlle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: If this topic can be closed please click the 'delete' or 'close' link below the tags to the question.